# Creating instance of class

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, instance

I wonder, is it safe to create an instance of a class to then access methods inside of it. Someone said something about dependency injection though never went further. For example:

```
private static WordfilterController instance;

public static WordfilterController GetInstance()
{
    if (instance == null)
        instance = new WordfilterController();
    return instance;
}
```

This allows me to access methods like this:

```
WordfilterController.GetInstance().CheckString("hi");
```

My question is, is this optimal, and is it safe?

Comment: I'm curious to know what the dependency injection comment was. I don't see how it's relevant to this question, but if was relevant to an earlier question and that question is relevant to this question then that comment is relevant to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is contained in the `WordfilterController` class, what you're example illustrates is a simple version of the *Singleton* design pattern you can read more in [Jon Skeet's](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx) post.

**It wouldn't be if it had a public constructor tho.**

Your code chunk has nothing to do with *Dependency Injection* and it's also not thread-safe, but it should do the job in most cases.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @MickyD, Is it clearer this way?

Comment: Much better my friend :)